# How to determine if a record already exists in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm doing a VB with Access database and I want to create a button. Which savebutton with checking where the data that try to insert is duplicated or not compare with my database.

This my code, and the problem is whatever I enter it just show the user already exists.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  MyConn = New OleDbConnection
  MyConn.ConnectionString = connString

  MyConn.Open()
  If (ComboBox2.Text = "") And (ComboBox3.Text = "") 
      And (TextBox3.Text = "") And (ComboBox4.Text = "") 
  Then
   MsgBox("Please fill-up all fields!")
  Else
   Dim theQuery As String = ("SELECT * FROM Table1 
      WHERE"" [Subject_Code]=@Subject_Code ,[Day]=@Day, 
              [Times]=@Times , [Lecture]=@Lecture and [Class_Room]=@Class_Room""")

   Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(theQuery, MyConn)
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject_Code", TextBox6.Text)
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", ComboBox2.Text)
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Times", ComboBox3.Text)
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lecture", TextBox3.Text)
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class_Room", ComboBox4.Text)

   Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
     'User already exists
     MsgBox("User Already Exist!")
   Else
    Dim Update As String = "INSERT INTO [Table1] 
     ([Subject_Code], [Subject],
      [Day], [Times], [Level],[Semester], [Lecture],[Class], [Class_Room])
     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

     Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(Update, MyConn)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox6.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox1.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", ComboBox2.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", ComboBox3.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", ComboBox1.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", ComboBox6.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", TextBox3.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", ComboBox5.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", ComboBox4.Text)
      MsgBox("New Data Is Saved")
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     End Using
   End If
  End Using
 End If
```

Comment: What are the `""` doing in your SELECT string?

Comment: @Clavert Here exists an unwritten rule: Avoid the word `urgent`.

Comment: @reporter: it's actually [very written](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) `;-)`.

Comment: Sorry, if i din put "" its error.. so what sld i change for?

Comment: Don't all of those `WHERE` clauses need concatenating with `AND`?

Comment: why don't you create an index at table level to prevent duplicates?

Comment: Shouldn't `If (ComboBox2.Text = "") And (ComboBox3.Text = "") And TextBox3.Text = "") And (ComboBox4.Text = "") Then` be `If (ComboBox2.Text = "") Or (ComboBox3.Text = "") Or (TextBox3.Text = "") Or (ComboBox4.Text = "") Then` ?

Comment: @Andre: thanks for spotting this is VB.net rather than VBA - the question tags led me astray. In relation to your edit, I think the community prefers leaving some keywords in the title, even though they are also in the tags - sidebar features like Hot Network Questions benefit from the extra title specificity. (We do however try to iron out bar/slash hacks such as `VB.net | Access | How to determine if a record already exists?` though - urgh `:-)` ).

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a quick look at your theQuery variable, it may just have been malformed from where you have typed it into SO, but if not try:

```
  Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 " & 
                           "WHERE [Subject_Code] = @Subject_Code " & 
                           "AND [Day] = @Day " & 
                           "AND [Times] = @Times " & 
                           "AND [Lecture] = @Lecture " & 
                           "AND [Class_Room] = @Class_Room"
```

Your check for a pre existing user is based upon 5 fields, the insert for new data has 9 fields. Without knowing the business case I can't be sure if this is correct or if the missing 4 fields are actually important to the check and causing unexpected rows to be returned.

Personally my next steps would be:

1. Put a breakpoint on the AddWithValue statements and check the values
   are what you expect
2. Run the query with the values in SSMS/Access or equivalent and check the rows that come back are what you expect